# Get filename from input [type='file'] using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is the uploaded form.

```
<form class="alert alert-info">
    <div>
        <b id = "select_file" class="span3" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; ">Please select image</b>
        <input class="span3" type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" style="display:none " />
        <input disabled="true" type="button" value="Upload image" class="btn" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I use the following script to open a window with files. I want to show a file name in `<b id = 'select_file'>`.

How can I do this?

```
$('#select_file').click(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    $('#image_file').show().focus().click().hide();

    var filename = $('#image_file').val();
    _this.html(filename);

    $('.btn').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have to do this on the change event of the `input type file` this way:

```
$('#select_file').click(function() {
    $('#image_file').show();
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#image_file').change(function() {
        var filename = $('#image_file').val();
        $('#select_file').html(filename);
    });
});​
```

Comment: It's return a string that contain 'fakepath'. What is that?

Comment: it's nature of browser security, browsers usually hide file path

Comment: @Mikalai how do you pass this image's data to PHP using AJAX? I am getting the string 'Object file' every time I try to pass the image data. Any tips?

Answer (score 97):

Getting the file name is fairly easy. As matsko points out, you cannot get the full file path on the user's computer for security reasons.

```
var file = $('#image_file')[0].files[0]
if (file){
  console.log(file.name);
}
```

Comment: the brawser is Chrome. After second click on Please select the file ... The name of is showing in console.

Comment: or `var filename = $('#image_file')[0].files[0]['name']`

Comment: nevermind… I see now what you're doing, checking if the file object exists first.

Answer (score 9):

There is no jQuery function for this. You have to access the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) element and check the files property.

```
document.getElementById("image_file").files[0];
```

Or

```
$('#image_file')[0].files[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

This was a very important issue for me in order for my site to be multilingual. So here is my conclusion tested in Firefox and Chrome.

jQuery trigger comes in handy.

So this hides the standard boring `type=file` labels. You can place any label you want and format anyway. I customized a script from http://demo.smarttutorials.net/ajax1/. The script allows multiple file uploads with thumbnail preview and uses PHP and MySQL.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name='imageform' role="form"    ="imageform" method="post" action="upload_ajax.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="select_file">Select a file</div>
        <input class='file' type="file" style="display: none " class="form-control" name="images_up" id="images_up" placeholder="Please choose your image">
        <div id="my_file"></div>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="loader" style="display: none;">
        Please wait image uploading to server....
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="image_upload" id="image_upload" class="btn"/>
</form>

$('#select_file').click(function() {
    $('#images_up').trigger('click');
    $('#images_up').change(function() {
        var filename = $('#images_up').val();
        if (filename.substring(3,11) == 'fakepath') {
            filename = filename.substring(12);
        } // Remove c:\fake at beginning from localhost chrome
        $('#my_file').html(filename);
   });
});
```

Comment: The sample HTML is not well-formed. E.g. near "`="imageform"`" and `<input class='file'`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this to Get filename from input [type='file'] using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
            var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
            alert('The file "' + fileName +  '" has been selected.');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Taken from @ [jQueryPot](http://www.jquerypot.com/get-filename-from-input-type-file-using-jquery/)

Comment: how can I get it in button click

Answer (score 3):

**Using Bootstrap**

Remove **form-control-file** Class from input field to avoid unwanted horizontal scroll bar

Try this!!

```js
$('#upload').change(function() {
    var filename = $('#upload').val();
    if (filename.substring(3,11) == 'fakepath') {
        filename = filename.substring(12);
    } // For Remove fakepath
    $("label[for='file_name'] b").html(filename);
    $("label[for='file_default']").text('Selected File: ');
    if (filename == "") {
        $("label[for='file_default']").text('No File Choosen');
    }
});
```

```css
.custom_file {
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="upload" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Upload Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="text-center form-control-file custom_file" id="upload" name="user_image">
    <label for="file_default">No File Choosen </label>
    <label for="file_name"><b></b></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#filetosend").prop('files')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the properties you want passing an argument to your callback function (like `evt`), and then accessing the files with it (`evt.target.files[0].name`) :

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $("main").append('<input type="file" name="photo" id="upload-photo"/>');
  $('#upload-photo').on('change',function(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.files[0].name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var file = $('#YOURID > input[type="file"]');
file.value;   // filename will be,`

In Chrome, it will be something like `C:\fakepath\FILE_NAME` or `undefined` if no file was selected.

It is a limitation or intention that the browser does not reveal the file structure of the local machine.

Answer (score -1):

If selected more 1 file:

```
$("input[type="file"]").change(function() {
   var files = $("input[type="file"]").prop("files");
   var names = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.name; });
   $(".some_div").text(names);
});
```

`files` will be a `FileList` object. `names` is an array of strings (file names).

Comment: how to access the fileList object in PHP?

Answer (score -2):

This isn't possible due to security reasons. At least not on modern browsers. This is because any code getting access to the path of the file can be considered dangerous and a security risk. Either you'll end up with an undefined value, an empty string or an error will be thrown.

When a file form is submitted, the browser buffers the file temporarily into an upload directory and only the temporary file name of that file and basename of that file is submitted.

Comment: The temporary file ame that you may see on the server side is not generated on the client side.  That is done on the server side.  The path is not accessible but the file name itself is.

Comment: @DennisDay the server utilizes the filepath to know what the *file* actually is.  The OP is using a form, he's using some sort of server processing that takes the form as a submission.