# Get value of input of type file

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div>
  <a>browse<input type="file" name="annex"></a>
  <span class="filename"></span>
</div>
```

I am using this markup to style the file input with CSS.

I would like to show the file name (filename.ext) in the span with class "filename".

I tried the following with JQuery:

```
$('.file').on('file', function (event, files, label) {
  $('.path').html($(this).val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, ''));
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

The span is still empty and the alert result is also empty.

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/638/

Comment: Your selector is looking for class = file.  Either add the class to your input, or change your selector to look for the type = file attribute: $('[type="value"]')

Comment: Posted a new answer about this...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function (event, files, label) {
    var file_name = this.value.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '')
    $('.filename').text(file_name);
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YKkGC/)

Answer (score 0):

This is *not possible with JavaScript*, as it is considered insecure for the script to read your local file paths.

However, if you're creating an HTML5 site, you might be luckier with the [HTML5 File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Also, you might want to check [this interesting link over here](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+file+upload).....

Answer (score 0):

You can read it, but you can't set it. so it won't have a value until you click on it and pick a file.

Even then, the value will likely be mangled with something like c:\fakepath\ to keep the details of the user's filesystem private.

Reference [Can't get value of input type="file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903323/cant-get-value-of-input-type-file)

Try out this link [Get filename from input [type='file'] using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780309/jquery-get-filename-from-input-type-file)