# How to get real path of file?

Tags: php, jquery

After submitting image upload form, i want to get the real path of the choosen file
like C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\koala.jpg
no matter from which drive it was selected it should return correct path (like above)
i tried both with php and jquery but can't get the expected result.
this is my code

```
$('#getrealpath').change(function (){
            $('#realpath').val($(this).val());
        });
```

it returns C:\fakepath\koala.jpg

and php

```
realpath($_FILES['image']['name'])
```

you can help me with any php/jquery code.
thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Comment: you can't nor should you need to

Comment: You can not have this realpath in your javascript, due to security, this is not possible in common browsers check the link from @haim770

Comment: checked it and thanks for you help

Comment: hello @Niroj Adhikary


file always first stored in "tmp" folder on form submit you need to move that file to site folder `move_uploaded_file()` 

check this parameter http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

pass two parameter filename and destination No need to real path

BEFORE FORM SUBMIT YOU CAN GET FILE NAME USING:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780309/jquery-get-filename-from-input-type-file

check this link